# Why do 1000 rpm and 10 rpm DC motors cost the same?

Tags: motor

Today I was going to buy a motor online, and saw that 10 rpm and 1000 rpm DC motors cost the same. How is it possible to change the rpm without requiring any additional parts cost?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* shail, to make this less opinion based, could you please provide links to the two motors (just paste in the URLs, we can edit them into proper links later), that way the answers can be updated with facts rather than speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Revolutions per minute (RPM) is merely one of the parameters of a DC motor. Another important criterion is torque, which may be understood as the power output capability of the motor. Perhaps the 10 RPM motor is capable of driving a heavier load, and the 1000-RPM motor simply cannot reach its nominal revolutions per minute with even a very light load.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the difference between the two motors will be the number of times the wire is wrapped around the [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_%28electric%29).

There is a [tradeoff between RPM and torque in DC motors](http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html#tscurve), where more windings mean more torque (but a lower maximum RPM).  Depending on the characteristics of the motor, some manufacturers use a thicker wire when building motors with fewer windings -- allowing more current to flow.

So, it's possible that the same amount of copper wire is being used for both motors, or that it's near enough not to bother with pricing the different motor types differently.